# How to extract polar plot information in Python?

Tags: python

I want to extract polar coordinates from the plot. There exists a matrix that has 10 rows and 2 columns a and b. This matrix has the numbers that created the polar plot.

But what I am looking for is a matrix that has the polar coordinates that are already plotted.

Example: the first row (meaning, information about the first point) would include the x,y,radius and theta/angle or any other useful information from the plot that were previously not there in the original matrix.

Think of polar plotting as a transformation that was implemented on the matrix in the `for` loop and I want to extract the new numbers resulted from the output polar plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sample= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

fig  = plt.figure()
fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

data = sample


for i in data:
    a=i+min(data)
    b=i+max(data)

    plt.polar(a,b, '.', c='black')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This smells like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Is it important to actually get information from matplotlib about what was plotted? It seems to me that you will have an easier time doing the transformation from polar to rectangular coordinates yourself. I think you should clarify what information you have in your original data, and what information you would like to extract with your program.

Comment: My point in doing the polar transformation is to arrive at a different representation of my data. From there, I would like to get extract new information that would otherwise not be available in my original data as I mentioned in the question. The information I have in my original data are just columns of random numbers and I am trying to prove that they can be represented with a different set of numbers extracted from the polar plot.

Answer (score 0):

Even after your clarification I am a little confused by the code example. But I am pretty sure the code below answers your question.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.random.random((10,1)) # same as "a" in your example
y = np.random.random((10,1)) # same as "b" in your example

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.title("Rectangular coordinates")
plt.show()

th = np.arctan2(y,x)
r = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

# Should show the same plot as above, just with different margins/aspect ratio/grid lines
plt.polar(th,r)
plt.title("Polar coordinates")
plt.show()
```

It's just as easy to go in reverse, getting the rectangular coordinates if you assume your random data is representing data in polar coordinates.